# WebView simulate click

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a custom WebView and I want to simulate a click when I get a MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN. I don't want to have any kind of input on the WebView , I must not even make it clickable(.setClickable(false)). So what i have done is override the  onTouchEvent() in my custom WebView to return false.

this works fine but I'm missing the click. I have seen in the source code of WebView that it send messages to  class called WebViewCore but this communication is done differently in every version of android.

Does anyone knows how can I programmatically  send a click to a webView?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
public class VoidWebView extends WebView {


    public VoidWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    public VoidWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                //tell the webview that a click has been performed , it doesn't matter where the click happened

        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the performClick() method of the `View`.

You can get some more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Pass up and down event to super class.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
         super.onTouchEvent(event);
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to pass the event to the super class, this is because it causes unexpected behaviour in the layout containing the WebView. That is why I need to send the click message myself